# WordPress wp_enqueue_style not working

Tags: css, wordpress, styles

I was trying to include a css file in my WordPress plugin admin page. I have tried below method

```
function theme_name_scripts() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'jspro', '/includes/parts/css/jspro.min.css');
}
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work. My css file path is correct as given here,and I have tried almost every method. Any idea?

Comment: `wp_enqueue_style` takes an absolute path. What's the absolute path to your css?

Comment: plugins_url().'includes/parts/css/jspro.css this is where my css exists

Comment: I'm guessing you're referring to your own plugin's folder, rather than the root `yoursite.com/wp-content/plugins` folder, when you say `plugins_url()`?

Comment: Yes I am. But I have tried giving full path directly also. That is too not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have an absolute URL to your css file, and hook into the correct admin hook (in this case, `'admin_init'`):

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'theme_name_scripts' );

function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'jspro', plugins_url('includes/parts/css/jspro.min.css', __FILE__));
}
```

Comment: If I add this to my main plugin file, will it call this css to all admin pages of this plugin? That is what I need but currently it is not working

Comment: I edited my answer a bit...but it depends upon where you are calling this from. If your .php file is in a subdirectory, you may need to use PHP's [dirname()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) function. Read more about [plugins_url() in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url).

Answer (score 1):

In admin mode there is a special hook '[admin_enqueue_scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts)' that WP reccomends to use.

```php
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts');

function theme_name_scripts() {
   wp_enqueue_style('jspro', '/includes/parts/css/jspro.min.css');
}
```

Also, hook [can also be used](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/#div-comment-70) to check the name of current admin page:

```php
function theme_name_scripts( $hook ) {
    if ( $hook != 'edit.php' )
        return;
    wp_enqueue_style('jspro', '/includes/parts/css/jspro.min.css');
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Could you explain exactly what this does, so as to be a better answer for future readers?

Comment: Hey, how do U do! In admin mode WP uses 'admin_enqueue_scripts' hook instead of 'wp_enqueue_scripts'.